# Windows 2000 Groups

Tags: windows-2000, user-groups

Which default group is created on Windows 2000 domain controllers to allow members to administer domain controllers, but does not allow members to administer user and group accounts?
is it : Server operators , Account operators or Administrators?
 i think Account operators has the right to do such tasks ,but server operators has to do with back up files and force shut down , and Administrators has the full control to do all so is it Server operators ?

One more thing , is there any group called "Domain operators" ?!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Server Operators group  , Members of the Server Operators group have special permissions to administer domain controllers.

Kind regards